# I am a novice and am trying to work with Sikuli. Can Eclipse be used to code with Sikuli?

Tags: sikuli

Can sikuli be integrated with Eclipse to write code?

Answer (score 4):

If I enter **sikuli eclipse** into google, the first result is [this page: http://doc.sikuli.org/faq/040-other-ide.html](http://doc.sikuli.org/faq/040-other-ide.html) which explains how to use Sikuli in Eclipse. I used this guide myself and found it no problem to get it to work.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I am now successfully using Sikuli with Eclipse.